# How to cleverly solve this kind of equations?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, reference-request, recurrence-relations

> Suppose we have the following equations where $0<p<1$:
>
> \begin{align} a_{i,j}&=pb_{i+1,j} + (1-p)b_{0,j} \\
>  b_{i,j}&=pa_{i,j+1}+(1-p)a_{i,0} \end{align} with the boundary
>   conditions: \begin{align} b_{3,j}=1 \qquad\text{  where $0\le i< 3$}\\
>  a_{i,3}=0 \qquad\text{  where $0\le j< 3$} \end{align}
>   **We are asked to get $a_{0,0}$**

I can solve it by getting a set of equations such as:
\begin{align}
a_{0,0} & = pb_{1,0} + (1-p) b_{0,0}\\
b_{1,0} & = pa_{1,1} + (1-p) a_{1,0}\\
b_{0,0} & = pa_{0,1} + (1-p) a_{0,0}\\
a_{1,1} & = pb_{2,1} + (1-p) b_{0,1}\\
\vdots
\end{align}

however this seems too complicated and very easy to calculate wrong. If we let the number $3$ in the boundary condition to be a much larger number $n$, then this method is impossible to solve by hand.

**I want to know if there is a better way or more analytical way to solve this kind of equation?**

Comment: these are called linear difference equations-https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_difference_equation

Comment: Note that you can easily decouple the variables.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD decouple varialbes eventually will bring you to $a_{3,3}$ which is not defined.

Comment: @vidyarthi not exactly same, here I have two time index...

Comment: @fizis not exactly same, but somewhat related. Your equation can be converted to homogenous form, from which you may use characteristic equation, I think

Comment: @vidyarthi you suggestion is same as YotengoUnLCD, but it will bring the $a_{3,3}$ which is undefined, and still there are two index.

Comment: In your boundary conditions, you would not have exchanged indexes? ¿i by j and vice versa?

Comment: @Piquito i, and j has a range, they represent many possible numbers.

Comment: @Piquito in short, the boundary condition is ok.

Comment: You can only do it cleverly by way of your cleverness.

Comment: @Alephnull I haven't get your point, but I am curious of your clever way.

Comment: If you take $n$ off to infinity, I can see some analytical path forward via generating functions. However, for finite $n$, what can be conceptually simpler than solving a system of linear equations? Just because a process is error prone does not make it not clever. Put the system of equations into a matrix and use careful Gaussian elimination to solve it. Or use a computer with symbolic equations (e.g. Mathematica) or construct the matrix for numerical values of $n$ and $p$ and solve using your a matrix solver; then iterate over small steps of $p$ to get the solutions as a function of $p$.

Comment: It looks the answers are a war of Matlab v Mathematica now... ;)

Comment: @floorcat I don't want to trigger a holy war ;). After all, mathematician are more sensible than programmers.

Comment: Lawlz

I'll hold my tongue now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to place the values $a_{i,j}$ $b_{i,j}$  (for $0\le i,j<3$) in two matrices $A,B$

Then you get the equivalent system of matrix equations:

$$\begin{array}{rcl} A &=& C B + D \tag{1}\\
B &=& A \, C^T 
\end{array}$$

where
$C=\begin{pmatrix}
q & p &0\\
q & 0 &p\\
q & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$ and $D=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 &0\\
0 & 0 &0\\
p & p & p
\end{pmatrix}$

(where $q=1-p$)

Or
 $$A = C A C^T +D \tag{2}$$

Considering that $A$ is the unknown, this corresponds to $9$ linear equations with $9$ unknowns, so it's in principle solvable. Actually this is known as the [discrete Lyapunov equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_equation). Sadly, while it's quite simple to solve it numerically (basically you build a $9 \times 9$ matrix to express it -and solve it- as a basic linear equation $Ax = b$), it does not seem easy to express the solution (in particular, $A_{0,0}$) in general, as a function of $p$ .

An example (in Octave/Matlab) :

```
>> p = 0.3 ; 
>> q=p-1;
>> C=[ q p 0 ;  q 0 p ; q 0 0]
C=
   0.70000   0.30000   0.00000
   0.70000   0.00000   0.30000
   0.70000   0.00000   0.00000
>> D = [0 0 0; 0 0 0 ; p p p]
D =
  0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
  0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
  0.30000   0.30000   0.30000
>> A=reshape((eye(9)-kron(C,C))\reshape(D,9,1) ,3,3)
A =
  0.50516   0.47077   0.36055
  0.53822   0.50826   0.38327
  0.64639   0.62324   0.54753

  >> C*A*C'+D-A % check
ans =
  0.0000e+000  0.0000e+000  -5.5511e-017
 -1.1102e-016  -1.1102e-016  -5.5511e-017
 -1.1102e-016  1.1102e-016  0.0000e+000
```

This agrees with the formula from rajb245's answer : $a_{0,0}(0.3)=0.5051590567552$

Comment: $a_{3,3}$ is undefined, because you never need to reach $a_{3,3}$ to get $a_{0,0}$, how can you write $a$ as a matrix?

Comment: @fizis : The matrix dimension is $3\times 3$, it includes from $a_{0,0}$ to $a_{2,2}$

Comment: I also can't see how your two matrix equation derives, they are symmetric in the original form, but no longer in your matrix form.

Comment: If by "no symmetric" you mean the $D$ term: that comes from the different boundary conditions

Comment: I have check your two equations with $n=2$, this is really a nice simplification. I wonder how you can see it through and write out the matrix form.

Comment: Do you use mathematica? I have a short script solving $n=2$, but it always gives zero. `q = 1 - p;
a = {{a00, a01}, {a10, a11}};
c = {{q, p}, {q, 0}};
d = {{0, 0}, {p, p}};
eqn = a == c a Transpose[c] + d
Solve[eqn, {a00, a01, a10, a11}]`

Comment: _" I wonder how you can see it through and write out the matrix form"_  It's quite straightforward, once you define $a_{i,j}$ as the $(i,j)$ element of matrix $A$ the equations translate directly to a matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 3):

A general method that works for any size $n$ and is not prone to errors is to use a computer algebra system (such as Mathematica) to directly solve the system for any size $n$. Given that this is a well-posed finite linear system of equations, I don't see any clever tricks; if you want to solve such a system, you (or the computer) has to do the tedious work of solving it using elimination of variables until you get the result. Whether you call this Gaussian elimination or LU decomposition, you have to substitute the equations into each other and keep track of your operations without error in order to arrive at the correct result. In much more complicated problems (such as solving PDEs such as the wave or heat equation or Maxwell's equations), once you reduce things to a finite system of linear equations, you let the computer solvers take over. The fact that your problem is of this simple class to begin with leads me to believe there really aren't any clever tricks to be played here.

For the approach, I transcribed the two equations you presented into Mathematica, then set it up to explicitly calculate all the equations for $i,j\in\{0,1\ldots n\}$, enforced the boundary conditions for $i=n+1$ and $j=n+1$, then told it to solve the equations. For $n=2$, the solution is:
$$
a_{0,0} =  -\frac{p^8-2 p^7+p^6-p^4+p^3-1}{p^9-4 p^8+6 p^7-4 p^6+3 p^4-3 p^3+2}
$$
A happy consequence is that all the unknowns are solved for simultaneously by Mathematica's algorithms.

Here is a plot of $a_{0,0}$ as a function of $p$:

[image: Plot of a00]

And here is the Mathematica code I used:

```
(*setup the right hand side functions*)
a[i_,j_] := p Subscript[b, i+1,j] + (1-p) Subscript[b, 0,j]
b[i_,j_]:=p Subscript[a, i,j+1] + (1-p) Subscript[a, i,0]
n=2; (*works for any order n*)
(*set the variables equal to the right hand sides, enforce the boundary conditions, and collect into one list*)
aEqs = Table[Subscript[a, i,j]==a[i,j],{i,0,n},{j,0,n}]/.{Subscript[a, i_,n+1]->0,Subscript[b, n+1,j_]->1}//Flatten[#,1]&;
bEqs = Table[Subscript[b, i,j]==b[i,j],{i,0,n},{j,0,n}]/.{Subscript[a, i_,n+1]->0,Subscript[b, n+1,j_]->1}//Flatten[#,1]&;
Eqs = Join[aEqs,bEqs];
(*collect all the variables into one list*)
aVars = Table[Subscript[a, i,j],{i,0,n},{j,0,n}]//Flatten[#,1]&;
bVars = Table[Subscript[b, i,j],{i,0,n},{j,0,n}]//Flatten[#,1]&;
Vars = Join[aVars,bVars];
(*Run the solver*)
Soln = Subscript[a, 0,0]/.Solve[Eqs,Vars][[1]]//Simplify;
TraditionalForm[Soln]
Plot[Soln,{p,0,1}]
```

Comment: I wonder if mathematica can solve matrix equations directly. The other answer gives the simplified form, it will be a good practice if that match your solution..

Comment: You must be a mathematica pro

Comment: The other answer is for one value of $p$, but the approach is similar. I can set $p$ to a numerical value and generate the matrix equations if that would be helpful.

Comment: what I mean is that the other answer simplifies the equation to only one, which is a big analytical improvement if that simplification really works well